# How to know if child is null in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

this is the android code which is relevant:

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        mLoginProgress.dismiss();
                        final String current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        String deviceToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
                        DatabaseReference itsUser = mUsersDatabaseReference.child(current_user_id);
                        DatabaseReference itsPilot = mPilotsDatabaseReference.child(current_user_id);
```

I have the current_user_id, and I want to know if it's a User or a Pilot.
So I have these 2 urls:
https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/...-96d4e/database/airpal-96d4e/data/Users/mbGyPElqNphTritK5iyN8bXadSK2

https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/...-96d4e/database/airpal-96d4e/data/Pilots/mbGyPElqNphTritK5iyN8bXadSK2

This is the status:
As you can easily see, my current_user_id is 'User' and not a 'Pilot'. 
I just want to do it by code.

[image: stat]

And when I insert them into the chrome in 1 of them the child is null, and in one of them it has fields.

How can I recognize it ?

Reading the dataSnapshot gives me all of the fields seperately and I prefer clearer solution. Thanks

Edit: 
Solution is by value event listener and snapShot only

```
itsUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            Log.d("dDebug","i'm here");
                            pilotBool = (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() == 0);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: We can't see your firebase console links.  Please edit your question to describe what you're trying to do without linking to the console.

Comment: I understand you don't see the urls, anyway I added screen shots that helps understand, please tell me if something is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't know anything that's in your database until you query for it to get a snapshot with the contents at the location of the query.  There's no special query to check for existence that doesn't involve a snapshot.

Comment: You query the location you want to know about using addListenerForSingleValueEvent.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)